# layout parameters lost after adding view resource to application ini

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

I want to add a view helper path in an existing project. To do this I have added the following line to my application.ini:

```
resources.view[] =
```

And in my bootstrap file:

```
$this->bootstrap("view");
$view = $this->getResource("view");
$view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . "/../library/MyPath", MyNamespace");
```

Now I am indeed able to add view helpers to my path, so no problem there.

However, variables that I have added to the view in my Action Helpers are suddenly no longer accessible inside my views. I can retreive them inside my layout as usual so I know they get assigned properly.

I assign a variable in my Action Helper in the postDispatch:

```
$view = $this->getActionController()->view;
$view->myVar = $this->var;
```

Then in my layout

```
Zend_Debug::dump( $this->myVar );
```

results in: (string) "myVar contents"

And in my view

```
Zend_Debug::dump( $this->myVar );
```

results in: null

Since this is an existing project I need a general solution that I can use in either my bootstrap or application.ini

Comment: maybe it's as simple as `return $view;` in your bootstrap. Probably not but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can add paths to your view from application.ini:

```
resources.view.helperPath.MyPrefix = "/path/to/helpers"
```

Hopefully this will fix the problem. I'm assuming that the way you do it, an existing view-instance is somehow overwritten, which destroy previous changes. You could try fetching the view from the frontcontroller, set the helper-path, and pass it back to the frontcontroller.

Comment: I have tried that option, unfortunately it produces the same results. It seems to me like two separate view instances are created, one instance for the layout, and one for the views. My view variables can still be accessed in the layout though.

Answer (score 0):

After some research this is what I found out.

*Edit: Removed text concerning differences between view variables and layout variables - see comments by @pieter and @david weinraub*

The postDispatch of the Action Helper fires AFTER the view is rendered, but BEFORE the layout is rendered. Therefore, any variables assigned to the view in the postDispatch of the action helper were unavailable in my views, they didn't exist yet.

I am very curious why this behaviour occurs ONLY when actively bootstrapping the view? I will leave the question unanswered, maybe someone can clarify this.

Comment: That is ofcourse not true. You can assign values to the view from everywhere you like (as long as you have access to the view object). Zend_View does not discriminate ;) The question is; why does your application have a separate Zend_View instance for Zend_Layout and for the ViewRenderer. This is usually the same object (as Zend_Layout actually retrieves the view object from the ViewRenderer by default). You might want to check your app if you assign a view instance to Zend_Layout anywhere.

Comment: @Pieter has hit on it. It sounds like you have two view instances floating around. In a typical flow, the instance assigned to the `ViewRenderer` (the one that the controller knows about) is the same one you bootstrapped and to which you assigned those view-helper paths. It sounds like there is some disconnect from this normal flow.

Comment: In cases where I have just had to force it, I have just manually jammed my view instance into the ViewRenderer. So in your bootstrap, after you add the view-helper paths, add: `Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer')->setView($view);`

Comment: I found out what happens, there's no separate instance. I will update my answer accordingly.